# Is there anyway to prevent the same JS/CSS file from being loaded multiple times when I have multiple Like buttons on a page?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, facebook-like

I have a page with multiple "Like" buttons on it, each pointing to a different URL.

Unfortunately, each of the "Like" buttons requests a JS and CSS script, and with many "Like" buttons on a page, identical scripts are loaded over and over again for each one.

For clarification, I am using xfbml and loading the JS-SDK asynchronously, and the "connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" file only gets pulled down once.

The files I'm having issues with are:

- http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yw/r/2RZcOthJlDD.js
- http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yx/r/QAxExOsrrUv.css

I assume this is because each inserted `<iframe>` element requires these resources.

If you look at http://techcrunch.com/ you will notice that they have circumvented this by lazily inserting the Facebook/Twitter etc. elements.  However, if you mouse over a few of them, you will notice that the same bits of JS and CSS are still uneccessarily loaded multiple times.

Does anyone have a solution that would limit each of these files to one request per page, regardless of the number of Like buttons on it?

Comment: Very well-written first question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you use the HTML5 code, this is no more the case. You have a base code, which you only use once on a page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And some code for like buttons, comments, ..., like this one, which you can use n-times on the page:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="YOUR_URL" data-send="true" data-width="450"></div>
```

This should only load the resources once.